# Problem with UTF-8 Encoding on SQLCE

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm using SQLCE for a database on a local application, I set that the encoding would be UTF-8, this encoding is supposed to accept the "ñ" and "Ñ", but when I save "españa" and after that I do a query to see all the tuples on the table, it shows "espa�a" with that weird replacement character. I was wondering if there's any way I could correct this.

update:
it seems that it's because my SO is English, and the database get that config.

Comment: Please provide us with more information.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: The data is probably stored correctly, but is not being displayed correctly. We need to know what you are using to display the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your SQL Studio (if that's where you query that table) settings for the proper encoding of the displayed data, as sometimes your regional settings mess the things a bit.

If you're displaying the result in a web application, use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```